# В чем ошибка (перевод в римское счисление)?

Tags: javascript

Как считаете, почему я получаю значение "undefined", а не римское число? Может, грубая ошибка?

```js
var letters = ["M", "D", "C", "L", "X", "V", "I"];
var nletters = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1];
var datain = prompt("Введите число, не превышающее 3999: ");
var out = "";
for (var a = 0; a < letters.length; a++ ) {
var calc = Math.trunc(datain/=nletters[a]); //Функция для "отсечения" дробной части
   for (var b = calc; b > 0; --b) { //Прибавляем буквы
      out+=letters[a];
   }
   if (calc == 0 || calc > 3) { //Вычитаем то, что уже должно быть записано
      datain-=calc*nletters[a];
   }
}
alert(out);
```

Comment: Вообще в римском счислении много правил, о которых вы можете узнать на [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B]. Но даже недоделанная вроде бы версия, почему-то не переводила арабские числа в формат римских, насколько помню.

Comment: попробуй описать словами алгоритм перевода, который ты пытаешься реализовать. Сейчас он у тебя не верен

Comment: @Grundy Вводится число. При делении на **a** элемент массива с числами (разряд в счислении) результат округляется в меньшую сторону (количество чисел разряда). И буква, обозначающая разряд, прибавляется к строке округленный результат раз. После из числа вычитается записанное. Начинается следующий разряд.

Comment: перенеси это в вопрос. отредактировать вопрос можно нажав кнопку [edit] под ним

Comment: @Grundy Он, я думаю, недоработанный. Хотя бы отсутствие записи чисел с вычитанием (IV, IX) можно считать уже серьезной ошибкой.

Comment: это не важно. Важно чтобы было описание алгоритма. Чтобы сразу была видна ошибка его реализации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

описание :

во первых

```
Math.trunc(datain/=nletters[a]);
```

Тут явно лишнее равно, оно записывало в datain результат деления из за этого начальные данные терялись

```
if (calc == 0 || calc > 3) { //Вычитаем то, что уже должно быть записано
   datain-=calc*nletters[a];
}
```

тут условие не нужно, отнимаем всегда, потому, что, если текущее число в datain  встречается то надо отнимать, если нет, то отнимем 0

как-то так :

```js
var letters = ["M", "D", "C", "L", "X", "V", "I"];
var nletters = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1];
var datain = prompt("Введите число, не превышающее 3999: ");
console.log(datain);
var out = "";
for (var a = 0; a < letters.length; a++) {
  var calc = Math.trunc(datain / nletters[a]);
  for (var b = calc; b > 0; --b) {
    out += letters[a];
  }
  datain -= calc * nletters[a];
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: добавь описание того, что именно ты поменял и почему не работало у автора вопроса

Comment: Выручили, спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: незачто, вот сделать бы чтобы, как-то по умному выводило числа типа  IV ...